# JQuery ui.dialog + ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

The code, loads some 'divs' and pops them all in a single dialog object (Sec1).

Each alert has a "dismiss" link(Sec2), with a JQuery event-listener that sends an ajax request, and shows a new dialog, created from the result (Sec3).

Seems like it's all working, but, with one problem: after clicking the 'dissmis', the result dialog is loaded in many (10, currently, in a previous version of the code, only 5..)

```
 //Sec1
 $("#alerts_list").dialog({
    title : "Alerts",
    resizable : false,
    dialogClass : "alerts",
    modal : true,
    maxHeight: $(window).height()- 20,
    buttons : [{
       text : "Done",
       click : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
       }
    }]
 });
```

The alerts code is:

HTML

```
//Sec2
<div class="alert<?php echo " " .$alert_class?>">
   <h3>Title</h3>
   <p class="alert-message">some text</p>
   <div class="toolbar">
      <a class="dismiss" href="/alerts/dismiss/1">dismiss</a>
      <a href="/alerts/">settings</a>
   </div>
</div>

//Sec3
$(".alert .toolbar a.dismiss").on('click',function(eve) {
   eve.preventDefault();
   $url = $(this).attr("href");
   $.get($url, null, function(data) {
      $("p").html(data).appendTo('body').dialog();
   });
});
```

Comment: How many `<p>` elements do you have in your page? `$("p")` selects all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to replace `$("p")` with `$("<p></p>")` or `$("<p>")`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! i used `$("P")` instead of `$("<P>")`. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This selector:

```
$("p").html(data).appendTo('body').dialog();
```

is affecting all your `<p>` elements.

Try to use a more specific selector.

Code:

```
//Sec3
$(".alert .toolbar a.dismiss").on('click',function(eve) {
   eve.preventDefault();
   $url = $(this).attr("href");
   $.get($url, null, function(data) {
      $(this).parent().siblings("p").html(data).appendTo('body').dialog();
   });
});
```